# What is the simplest way to change the behavior of a method during runtime?

Tags: c#

I have class called `Enemy`, and I want to have multiple types of enemies. Each `Enemy` will have different movement behavior, for example one might move straight at the player, one might maintain a certain distance, etc. What I would like to know is, what is the simplest way to have multiple different behaviors, preferably in one class?

My current idea is to use a `switch`, and include all the behavior in one method

```
public class Enemy
{
     public int health;
     public int damage;
     // etc etc

     public void Move(string type)
     {
        switch(type)
        {
             case "charge":
                  chargeMove();
                  break;
             case "maintain":
                  maintainMove();
                  break;
        }
     }

     private void chargeMove()
     {
          //stuff
     }

     private void maintainMove()
     {
          //stuff
     }

     //all the behaviors
}
```

What I would like to know, is it better to keep everything to one function like this, or to create a new class for each enemy type that inherits from `Enemy`? I would prefer to keep it to one class, so that all the enemies can be nicely stored into a `IList`, without me having to do any casting to use any of the specific functions.

Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks for all the responses, I think that I will use the interface method proposed by Alastair.

Comment: The best approach is to create class for each Enemy, that's *polymorphism* concept in OOP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this might be better suited on the [Gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site, you might want to consider looking into using some kind of composition.

Define a interface that describes a movement description. E.g.

```
public interface IMovementBehavior
{
    void Move(Enemy enemy);
}
```

so then you'll have a number of different behaviors that describe different movements.
eg.

```
public class ChargingMovementBehavior : IMovementBehavior { ... }
public class MaintainingMovementBehavior : IMovementBehavior { ... }
```

So your enemy contructor might have a defniniton like:

```
public Enemy(IMovementBehavior movementBehavior) { ... }
```

This means you can easily plug in and out different movement behaviors without having to fill your enemy class with all the different movement behaviors.

This is referred to as [Component Based Entities](http://entropyinteractive.com/2011/02/game-engine-design-component-based-entities/)

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a simple, flexible solution!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the [Strategy Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html) would be useful.

I think your suggestion of having a new class for each Enemy type is a good one. You can still store all the different objects of different enemy types in a single `List<Enemy>` since they all inherit from that class.

You could also consider having the `Enemy` class as abstract but it's not essential.

And if you really needed to know the specific type of a particular object in the list you could use [typeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) or [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

use delegate:

```
public delegate void DoSth();
```

at runtime, you associate this delegate to different instances.

See [msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) here.

Answer (score 1):

I would create multiple classes that derive from the same interface.  You can still have a list of the interface type.  This is a prime example of when [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) comes in handy.  Something like below:

```
interface iEnemy
{
    public void Move();
}

class Troll : iEmeny
{
    public void Move()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("troll moves!");
    }
}

class Ogre : iEmeny
{
    public void Move()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("ogre moves!");
    }
}
```

then in your code you can do this:

```
List<iEnemy> enemies = new List<iEnemy>();
enemies.Add(new Troll());
enemies.Add(new Ogre());

foreach(iEnemy e in enemies)
{
    e.Move();
}
//Output would be:
//troll move!
//ogre move!
```

This will also allow you to follow the [open/closed principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) which states that an entity should be open for extension but closed for modification.

Answer (score 0):

I would use derived classes.  That's pretty much what they're for - providing different behavior when the same methods are called.

If you don't want to cast, then define all your methods on the base class.  If a derived class doesn't override a particular method it will get whatever behavior is defined in the base class, not that it will matter if you never call it.  And if you want you can still have an integer "type" field if you don't want to use typeof and such.

```
public enum EnemyType
{
    Zombie,
    Vampire
}

public class Enemy
{
    private EnemyType mType;

    protected Enemy(EnemyType type) { mType = type; }

    public EnemyType getEnemyType() { return mType; }

    public void walk() { }

    public void attack() { }

    public void eatBrains() { }
}

public class Vampire : Enemy
{
    public Vampire : base(EnemyType.Vampire) { }

    public void walk()
    {
        // walk like a vampire
    }

    public void attack()
    {
        // attack like a vampire
    }

    // don't bother implementing eatBrains() because vampires don't do this
    // calling code will use getEnemyType() and won't bother call our eatBrains() method anyway
}
```

Comment: If only a certain type will `EatBrains`.. then you wouldn't include it in the base class.

Comment: He cited not wanting to cast as a reason not to use classes.  Since it's only for internal use anyway I was pointing out that he can get the benefits of classes without paying the costs of doing it "right".

Comment: Besides, it happens all the time that functions are added to base classes that aren't implemented in all subclasses.  toString() is a good example in most OO languages.

Comment: `ToString` is a bad example because there is a default implementation of it that all objects rely on (and is a fundamental part of the framework). That is my point though.. an `Enemy` derivative, that is.. say.. `PoliceOfficer` won't require an `EatBrains` method.

Comment: Wouldn't require it, but there's no reason it couldn't simply throw, as you frequently see, for example, with the methods that modify readonly collection classes.  They rarely implement a separate IReadOnlyCollection interface.  Or the methods that seek on a non-seekable stream.